# SSRS Pivoting a column

Tags: reporting-services, pivot

I current have this report layout

**<kbd>ProductNumber</kbd><kbd>Description</kbd><kbd>PackType</kbd><kbd>Dimension</kbd><kbd>Weight</kbd>**

<kbd>PN 1</kbd>                      <kbd>Desc PN1</kbd>      <kbd>InnerPack</kbd> <kbd>1x1x1</kbd>          <kbd>1</kbd>          

<kbd>PN 1</kbd>                      <kbd>Desc PN1</kbd>      <kbd>SinglePack</kbd><kbd>1x1x1.2</kbd>      <kbd>1.2</kbd>       

<kbd>PN 2</kbd>                      <kbd>Desc PN2</kbd>      <kbd>InnerPack</kbd> <kbd>2x2x2</kbd>          <kbd>2</kbd>          

<kbd>PN 2</kbd>                      <kbd>Desc PN2</kbd>      <kbd>SinglePack</kbd><kbd>2x2.2x2.2</kbd>   <kbd>2.3</kbd>       

<kbd>PN 3</kbd>                      <kbd>Desc PN3</kbd>      <kbd>BulkPack</kbd>  <kbd>3x3x3</kbd>          <kbd>3</kbd>

Now, my users want to pivot like this

**<kbd>InnerPack</kbd>                  <kbd>SinglePack</kbd>                      <kbd>BulkPack</kbd>**          
**<kbd>ProductNumber</kbd><kbd>Description</kbd><kbd>Dimension</kbd><kbd>Weight</kbd><kbd>Dimension</kbd><kbd>Weight</kbd><kbd>Dimension</kbd><kbd>Weight</kbd>**

<kbd>PN 1</kbd>                      <kbd>Desc PN1</kbd>      <kbd>1x1x1</kbd>         <kbd>1</kbd>          <kbd>1x1x1.2</kbd>       <kbd>1.2</kbd>                                         

<kbd>PN 2</kbd>                      <kbd>Desc PN2</kbd>      <kbd>2x2x2</kbd>         <kbd>2</kbd>          <kbd>2x2.2x2.2</kbd>    <kbd>2.3</kbd>                                         

<kbd>PN 3</kbd>                      <kbd>Desc PN3</kbd>                                                                     <kbd>3x3x3</kbd>          <kbd>3</kbd>

How can this be done? I'm using MS VS2008.

Thanks

TL

P.S. Thanks to ManisHearth to give me an idea how to create a table in post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this with a standard **Matrix**. Create a **Matrix** and add a a **Row Group** based on *ProductNumber* and a **Column Group** based on *PackType*. I also added a couple more rows to the Matrix to allow some more details in header. I had to split the column header cells to add the *Dimension* and *Weight* headers.

Add the detail values to the **Matrix** body - I removed the automatic **Sum** that was added to the *Weight* value, but that's not strictly necessary. It should look something like this in the designer:

[image]

One more thing to consider; your *PackType* groups aren't in alphabetical order, so I updated the **Column Group** sort expression for your required ordering. I used:

```
=Switch(Fields!PackType.Value = "InnerPack", 1
    , Fields!PackType.Value = "SinglePack", 2
    , Fields!PackType.Value = "BulkPack", 3)
```

Final result, matching your requirements:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ian. That will do it. Sorry for a slow respond. This is my first project using SSRS. So I still try to grasp your solution and the training video that I am watching. LOL.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the idea of sorting a field in SSRS, Ian. The PackType was not sorting by alphabet because it is being sorted in the database based on a predefined criteria by the users. I believe the sorting is based on how frequent the PackType is used. Thanks again.