# Count and group data by Year/month and by user

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[taskDB](
    [ticket] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [created] [date] NULL,
    [closed] [date] NULL,
    [rating] [varchar](50) NULL
[user] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023345', CAST(N'2019-09-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-01-17' AS Date), N'Low', N'John')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023346', CAST(N'2019-08-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-03' AS Date), N'Critical', N'Tom')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023347', CAST(N'2019-09-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-09-20' AS Date), N'Critical', N'Pete')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023348', CAST(N'2019-08-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-08-06' AS Date), N'Critical', N'John')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023349', CAST(N'2020-08-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium', N'Tom')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023350', CAST(N'2019-08-01' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium', N'Pete')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023351', CAST(N'2019-12-22' AS Date), CAST(N'' AS Date), N'High', N'Tom')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023352', CAST(N'2019-11-07' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium', N'John')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023353', CAST(N'2020-08-02' AS Date), CAST(N'' AS Date), N'Low', N'Pete')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023354', CAST(N'2019-08-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium'N, 'Tom')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023355', CAST(N'2019-010-02' AS Date), CAST(N'' AS Date), N'Low', N'John')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023356', CAST(N'2019-08-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Critical', N'John')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023357', CAST(N'2019-08-06' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-07-05' AS Date), N'Critical', N'Tom')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023358', CAST(N'2019-10-04' AS Date), CAST(N'' AS Date), N'Low', N'John')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023359', CAST(N'2019-12-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2020-02-25' AS Date), N'High', N'Pete')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023360', CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Medium', N'John')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023361', CAST(N'2020-08-02' AS Date), CAST(N'' AS Date), N'High', N'John')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023362', CAST(N'2019-09-02' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-10-06' AS Date), N'Critical', N'Pete')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023363', CAST(N'2019-10-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-11-08' AS Date), N'High', N'Pete')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023365', CAST(N'2019-10-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-12-08' AS Date), N'N/A', N'Pete')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023364', CAST(N'2019-11-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-11-05' AS Date), N'High', N'John')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023366', CAST(N'2020-06-03' AS Date), CAST(N'' AS Date), N'High', N'John')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023368', CAST(N'2019-08-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'High', N'John')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023367', CAST(N'2019-11-03' AS Date), CAST(N'' AS Date), N'N/A', N'Pete')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023371', CAST(N'2019-08-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'N/A', N'John')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[taskDB] ([ticket], [created], [closed], [rating], [user]) VALUES (N'023370', CAST(N'2019-08-03' AS Date), CAST(N'2019-08-05' AS Date), N'Critical', N'Pete')
GO
```

I am using the following query to count the number of tickets closed per month:

```
declare @FromDate datetime, 
        @ToDate datetime;

SET @FromDate = (Select min(created) From [dbo].[taskDB]);
SET @ToDate = (Select max(created) From [dbo].[taskDB]);

declare @openTicketsByMonth table (firstDayOfMonth datetime, firstDayNextMonth datetime, year int, month int, count int)

Insert into @openTicketsByMonth(firstDayOfMonth, firstDayNextMonth, year, month)

Select top  (datediff(month, @FromDate, @ToDate) + 1) 
                                                  dateadd(month, number, @FromDate),
              dateadd(month, number + 1, @FromDate),
             year(dateadd(month, number, @FromDate)),
              month(dateadd(month, number, @FromDate))
              from [master].dbo.spt_values 
              where [type] = N'P' order by number;

update R
Set R.count = (Select count(1) from [dbo].[taskDB] where created < R.firstDayNextMonth and (closed <= R.firstDayNextMonth and closed >= R.firstDayOfMonth)),
From @openTicketsByMonth R

select  year,
        month,
        count
from @openTicketsByMonth
```

I want to show the amount of tickets closed per month BY each user but I cannot get the INSERT INTO-Select statement include a set of rows for each users that outline the count by month. I am guessing i would need some sort of while loop that iterates over a temporary table that includes a list of distinct users to accomplish this. I know loops in MSSQL are not the best to implement. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop, derive year and month and then group by them

```
  ;WITH cteMonth as (
    SELECT ticket,created,closed,rating,[user] as UserName
        , YEAR(closed) as ClosedYear
        , MONTH(closed) as ClosedMonth
    FROM dbo.taskDB
  )SELECT COUNT(ticket) as ClosedCount, UserName, ClosedYear, ClosedMonth
  FROM cteMonth
  GROUP BY ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, UserName
  ORDER BY ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, UserName
```

Also, I don't think you need them for this, but in case I misunderstood your question and you want start and end dates in this you can back-derive them from year and month as follows

, DATEFROMPARTS (ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, 1) as firstDayOfMonth
, DATEADD(month, 1, DATEFROMPARTS (ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, 1)) as firstDayNextMonth

And one more thought, you don't need to put the results into a temporary table, but if you wanted to the syntax would be as follows

```
declare @ClosedTicketsByUser table (Username nvarchar(50), firstDayOfMonth datetime, firstDayNextMonth datetime, ClosedYear int, ClosedMonth int, ClosedCount int)

  ;WITH cteMonth as (
    SELECT ticket,created,closed,rating,[user] as UserName
        , YEAR(closed) as ClosedYear
        , MONTH(closed) as ClosedMonth
    FROM dbo.taskDB
  )
  INSERT INTO @ClosedTicketsByUser(ClosedCount, UserName, ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, firstDayOfMonth, firstDayNextMonth)
  SELECT COUNT(ticket) as ClosedCount, UserName, ClosedYear, ClosedMonth
    , DATEFROMPARTS (ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, 1) as firstDayOfMonth 
    , DATEADD(month, 1, DATEFROMPARTS (ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, 1)) as firstDayNextMonth
  FROM cteMonth
  GROUP BY ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, UserName
  ORDER BY ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, UserName

  SELECT * FROM @ClosedTicketsByUser
```

EDIT: In the comment you said you wanted zeros added back in so you can plot this, you can still do that with this structure by adding in a temporary table of USERS x DATES and COALESCE in the zeros over NULLS

```
;WITH cteTickets as (
    SELECT ticket,created,closed,rating,[user] as UserName
        , YEAR(closed) as ClosedYear
        , MONTH(closed) as ClosedMonth
    FROM dbo.taskDB
  ), cteUsers as (SELECT DISTINCT UserName FROM cteTickets
  ), cteDates as (SELECT DISTINCT ClosedYear, ClosedMonth 
        , DATEFROMPARTS (ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, 1) as firstDayOfMonth 
        , DATEADD(month, 1, DATEFROMPARTS (ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, 1)) as firstDayNextMonth
    FROM cteTickets
  ), cteCount as (SELECT COUNT(ticket) as ClosedCount, UserName, ClosedYear, ClosedMonth
      FROM cteTickets GROUP BY ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, UserName
  ) SELECT U.*, D.*, COALESCE(C.ClosedCount, 0) as ClosedCount
  FROM cteUsers as U CROSS JOIN cteDates as D 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cteCount as C ON C.UserName = U.UserName AND C.ClosedYear = D.ClosedYear AND C.ClosedMonth = D.ClosedMonth 
  ORDER BY firstDayOfMonth, UserName
```

EDIT: Here it is with a pivot table as requested in comments

```
  ;WITH cteTickets as (
    SELECT ticket,created,closed,rating,[user] as UserName
        , YEAR(closed) as ClosedYear
        , MONTH(closed) as ClosedMonth
    FROM dbo.taskDB
  ), cteUsers as (SELECT DISTINCT UserName FROM cteTickets
  ), cteDates as (SELECT DISTINCT ClosedYear, ClosedMonth 
        , DATEFROMPARTS (ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, 1) as firstDayOfMonth 
        , DATEADD(month, 1, DATEFROMPARTS (ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, 1)) as firstDayNextMonth
    FROM cteTickets
  ), cteCount as (SELECT COUNT(ticket) as ClosedCount, UserName, ClosedYear, ClosedMonth
      FROM cteTickets GROUP BY ClosedYear, ClosedMonth, UserName
  ), cteFinal as ( SELECT U.*, D.*, COALESCE(C.ClosedCount, 0) as ClosedCount
  FROM cteUsers as U CROSS JOIN cteDates as D 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cteCount as C ON C.UserName = U.UserName AND C.ClosedYear = D.ClosedYear AND C.ClosedMonth = D.ClosedMonth 
) 
SELECT firstDayOfMonth, [John], [Pete], [Tom] FROM (SELECT * FROM cteFinal) as F
PIVOT (MIN(ClosedCount) FOR UserName IN ([John], [Pete], [Tom])) as P
  ORDER BY firstDayOfMonth
```

Comment: So I thought about and approach such as this but this data is intended for data points on a graph. That being said this does not output a value for a user on a given month if they did not close any tickets.

Comment: Do you want a month if *no* users closed tickets in it, or just a zero if a user had no tickets in a month that others did?

Comment: yes a month if no users closed tickets would fit my needs

Comment: If i wanted to flip this so that the first column is the "firstDayOfMonth" field and then the columns after that were each user with their counts what would be the best way?

Comment: Use the same query except in  the last SELECT use a PIVOT TABLE. There are plenty of examples of PIVOT TABLE here, have a look and see if it makes sense.

Comment: BTW, if you'll create this plot more than once and with changing users, you might want to consider making a SSRS MATRIX report and exporting it to Excel, it automatically handles changing user names and date ranges. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036335/ssrs-pivoting-a-column and make Date your row group, UserName your Column group, and ClosedCount your value

Comment: Is there a way to create this plot  with changing users with out SSRS matrix? Problem is this is all needs to be in a query i can run when page loads to get live data.

Comment: Yes, you can use Dynamic Queries to do that, this should give you a good start. There are also many other posts about Dynamic Pivot Tables here and elsewhere. https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-pivot-tables-in-sql-server/